# Spring-core with @RabbitListener annotation does not fire bounded method

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to use rabbitmq @RabbitListener annotation in my methods so that whenever any message arrives, my method can get auto executed. Based on the official documentation provided [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/amqp.html#async-annotation-driven), I made the folowing config class

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.EnableRabbit;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME="myQueue";
    public static final String EXCHANGE_NAME="my_EXCHANGE";

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }
    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue myQueue() {
        return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME);
    }
   @Bean
   MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(myQueue());
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new RabbitMQListner());
        return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }
    @Bean
    FanoutExchange exchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, FanoutExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange);
    }
    @Bean
    MessagingService messagingService(){
        return new MessagingService();
    }
}
```

Then from my service class I used like this:-

```
@Component
public class MessagingService {
public void send(String msg){
        ApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RabbitConfiguration.class);


        AmqpTemplate template = context.getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);

        template.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME,"Hello from template "+msg);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues=QUEUE_NAME)
    private void receiveMessage(String order) {
        System.out.println("Hello"+order);
    }
```

The send method is working fine. But the receiveMessage method does not print the expected output. It should print the message as soon as it arrives in the queue. Instead, When I tried to apply @EnableRabbit annotation in my configuration file, I got `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` exception on runtime. The method receiveMessage does not even get executed.
 **You can ignore typo.**

Answer (score 0):

You need a method annotated with **@RabbitHandler** as well.

Example :

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Consumer {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
    @RabbitHandler
    public void handle(String msg)  {
        System.out.println("RCVD :: " + msg);
    }

}
```